# How to update tkinter window with another matplotlib plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'd like to make a tkinter window that displays a matplotlib graph without needing to create a new window.  I'm able to flip through graphs via destroying the window, but I'd like to avoid that since it's wildly annoying.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#global variables
global stopper
data = (([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]), ([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1]))
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

def Descision(event):
    print("go to next dataset")
    stopper.set(1)

for i in data:
    print(i)

    frame = Frame(window, width = 750, height = 750)    #make a new frame
    frame.pack()
    frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
    fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)

    stopper = IntVar(window, 0)     

    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    plot1.plot(i[0], i[1])

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)

    canvas.draw()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    window.bind("<Key>", lambda event : Descision(event))

    window.wait_variable(stopper)   #wait until user presses a key
    frame.destroy()
    #canvas.clear()     #"AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'clear'"
```

I'd like to switch from the graph made from data[0] to data[1], but the image produced is blank after destroying the frame.  Could anyone explain what I'm misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Like many others, I butted my head against the wall for a while and got it to work as I want.  Hope this helps someone out there!

```
#global variables
global stopper
data = (([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]), ([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1]), ([1,2,3,4,5],[3,3,3,3,3]))
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

frame = Frame(window, width = 750, height = 750)    #make a new frame & populate with a canvas
frame.pack()
frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)    #I don't understand this tbh
fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)

def Descision(event):
    print("go to next dataset")
    stopper.set(1)

for i in data:
    print(i)

    stopper = IntVar(window, 0)   
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)    #(re)insert a subplot

    l = plot1.plot(i[0], i[1])      #plot on said subplot

    canvas.draw()                   #draw plot on the canvas

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()   #put it all together

    window.bind("<Key>", lambda event : Descision(event))   #call another method

    window.wait_variable(stopper)   #wait until user presses a key
    fig.clear() #take out the last graphed canvas ... if you leave it then the axis overlap
```